# Angular HttpClientModule Body Syntax Issue

Tags: http-post, angular5, angular-httpclient

I am trying to make an HTTP request like this:

```
login(username, password) {
  let body = {
    userid: username,
    password: password
  }

  let options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
    withCredentials: true
  };

  let request = this.http.post(this.baseUrl, body, options);
  request.subscribe();
}
```

which is returning a 500 internal server error. However, if I modify the body variable to look like this:

```
login(username, password) {
  let body = 'userid=' + username + '&password=' + password;

  let options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
    withCredentials: true
  };

  let request = this.http.post(this.baseUrl, body, options);
  request.subscribe();
}
```

it works fine. I have seen the first version used in the documentation, but for some reason it doesn't work this way for me. I'm wondering:

A) Are these statements supposed to be equivalent? Is there a syntax issue? -or-

B) Is there a problem on the backend? In our server log, we're getting something like 'parameter @userIdentifier is expected but not supplied.'

I have to go with the one that works, but I'd like to use the syntax of the first statement if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Naturally, you want to go with the first example since you want to send JSON back and forth since it is the standard pattern and will be expected by other developers and module consumers in general. Your server needs to be configured receive and Par such requests with media type formatters. Without knowing what your server app is like it all it's just guesswork as to what the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information on the backend or on the specific 500 error message you are receiving, the only suggestion I have is to verify that your back-end schema matches the front-end model. Judging by the limited error message provided, it looks as though you may have mislabeled `userid` as `userIdentifier` in the backend.